# How do I select an image based on its path/url?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm tying to select images based on their URLs, but for some reason it's not playing ball:

Ultimately I'm after something like:

```
var imgs = $("img[@src='images/object.png']:not(:hidden)");
```

But even with something simple like:

```
$("img[@src='images/object.png']");
```

This error is thrown: "TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method".

If I omit the @ from the query:

```
$("img[src='images/object.png']");
```

I get no items returned.  I've copied and pasted the path directly from the generated html at runtime and it still refuses to return any items.  If I replace the src selector with an id selector, it returns the items.

This is the image tag generated at runtime:

```
<img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_object_1" src="images/object.png" style="height:16px;width:16px;border-width:0px;visibility:visible;display:inline;margin-right:3px;" />
```

I'm running jQuery 1.4.2 and I've checked all the documentation and all appears to be coded correctly.  I'm assuming this isn't a bug, but a misinterpretation on my part.  Can anyone she any light on this?

Cheers

Comment: Did you try the substring matching `src*=images/object.png` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use the `@` and be sure to include the full query too. If there is one.

```
$("img[src='/images/marketing/logo.png?1277792289']")[0]
```

You can do substring matching as well

```
$("img[src*='logo']")[0]
```

And the `:not` selector is in the wrong place.  It should not be in the attribute brackets.

```
$("img[src*='logo']:not(:visible)")[0]
```

Comment: Also the `:not(:hidden)` should come outside the `]`, like: `img[src='images/object.png']:not(:hidden)`

Comment: Correct, added it to the answer.

Comment: @casablanca: This was an error introduced in my writing of the question, in my original code, that was correct.  I've fixed it in my example.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @The Who: Interestingly if I remove the folder and use *= instead of a straight ='images/file.png' it works... is that something to do with the path I'm using?

Comment: @BenAlabaster I guessing here, but maybe the image is being translated as an absolute path? So the document root is "/foo/bar" the image is "images/file.png" jQuery might consider the src to be "/foo/bar/images/file.png"?  Likewise if you are "/" the image src would be "/images/file.png".  A big guess, but its all I got!

Comment: @The Who: Thanks, I'll have a play with it and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This used to be a bug in jQuery and apparently it still is.

Check out the following tickets:

- [Can not select a form using the action attribute](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/3245)
- [attr "action" of form and Selectors' attribute filter](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/2662)
- [selector by attribute "src" not working the same way as in 1.2.6](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4244)
- [IE7 "repairs" value of href atrribute by adding "http://..."](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/2747)

Essentially, what you have will work if you use the attributeEndsWith ($) or attributeContains (*) selectors because jQuery is not comparing your string against exactly what you put into the image src attribute, but against the full url path (ie, http:// ..... /images/object.png)