# javascript to alter image source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript I need help with.

I have an image with a src tag. I would like to take the value of the src an replace it with a static value. The src value though is variable but always in the same structure.

So if my image url is:

```
a/en-uk/images/items/item_123456789_1_185x185.jpg
```

with javascript, I want to modify this to

```
a/en-uk/images/items/item_not_found_185x185.jpg
```

baring in mind, the `a/en-uk/images/items/` and `123456789_1` parts the url are dynamic. So just want to replace `123456789_1` with `not_found`.

Any idea how I could do this with jquery? regexp?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `id` attribute to your image, for example `myImage` and then change it with 
JavaScript
HTML:

```
<img src='YOUR_OLD_SOURCE' id='myImage' ... />
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").src = "YOUR_NEW_SOURCE";
```

[Here is a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZnhZ/)

Note, you can also do it with `jQuery` although I did not think it required or helpful, the syntax would be:  `$("#myImage").attr('src','YOUR_NEW_SOURCE')`

If you'd like you don't have to give your image an ID, you can also select based on the url as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167806/how-do-i-select-an-image-based-on-its-path-url).

Comment: My preference is to modify existing source using a regexp or similar and not working with ids.

Comment: @amateur While it _is_ possible to use regular expressions to parse HTML in _this particular case_ it is generally a _really_ bad idea, more often than not regular expressions for parsing parts of HTML fail, more generally if you'd like you're welcome to come to the JS chat room where I will gladly explain _why_ that happens. However, take a look at the question I linked to at the bottom of my answer, you can select the "a" tags based on the URL they link to without modifying the source. I just thought that wasn't as clean.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#myImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('not_found','123456789_1'));
```

and vice versa

Comment: Please read the question. "baring in mind, the a/en-uk/images/items/ and 123456789_1 parts the url are dynamic."